# MySQL Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci (emojis)

Tags: mysql

The *Craft* docs call for using `utf8_unicode_ci` for MySQL collation. MySQL 5.5.3 introduced support for `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, which, I believe, is required to support the storage of emojis.

Does anyone have experience running *Craft* with the `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation? Any issues to watch out for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a database in MySQL in Craft 2, you can set the *default* charset and collation, so that any SQL statements that get executed that don't explicitly specify what charset/collation to use, MySQL will fall back on those.

Craft 2 will always explicitly set what to use based on what the `charset` and `collation` database config settings are set to in (by default `utf8` and `utf8_unicode_ci`).  Craft 3 does away with this and falls back on the database default.

However, if you set those config settings to `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and try to install Craft 2 you'll run into errors:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes.
```

Because MySQL's `utf8` implementation uses 3 bytes per character and `utf8mb4` uses 4-bytes, that pushes many of Craft's indexes over InnoDB's [767 byte limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814594/684).

It's worth noting that if the only place you think you'll need 4-byte support for emojis is in a Rich Text field, then Craft will [automatically HTML encode](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/helpers/StringHelper.php#L474) them so they fit in MySQL's 3-byte `utf8` charset.

If you need them outside the context of a Rich Text field, then your best bet would be to manually set just that column's charset and encoding to use `mb4` in the database directly.

It's also worth noting that the upcoming Craft 3 supports PostgreSQL where none of this matters and it just works.